# Как сделать анимацию вращающейся и увеличивающейся картинки внутри блока div?

Tags: javascript, css

Имеется `div class = "target"`

```
.target {
    margin-top: 2vmin;
    margin-left: 1vmin;
    margin-right: 1vmin;
    width: 0; height: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10vmin;
    border-top-color: salmon;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: salmon;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

Необходимо чтобы по клику из этого блока вылетала и "раскручивалась" png фото. Анимация должна заканчиваться остановкой вращения и помещаться в размеры target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('target')[0];
var targetImg = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

function spin() {
 target.classList.add('animeClass1');
 targetImg.classList.add('animeClass2');
}
```

```css
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateZ(1080deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin2 {
    0% {
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateZ(1080deg);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
.target {
    margin-top: 2vmin;
    margin-left: 1vmin;
    margin-right: 1vmin;
    width: 0; height: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10vmin;
    border-top-color: salmon;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: salmon;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}

.animeClass1 {
    animation: spin 2s 1 linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animeClass2 {
    animation: spin2 2s 1 linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.target img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -60.8px;
    left: -60.8px;
    transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
 <div class = "target" onclick="spin()">
  <img src="www.mydailycode.ru/goldreserv/1.png" alt="" height="121.59px" width="121.59px">
 </div>
```

не смог вставить картинку сюда

вот [тут](http://mydailycode.ru/test1/) можешь посмотреть

Answer (score 4):

Нашёл только в `jpg`, извините.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
  padding:20px 0;
}
.target{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
  width:300px;
}
.target img{
  width:100%;
  transform-origin:center;
  display:block;
  animation: spin 1.5s ease-out;
}
@keyframes spin{
  from{
    transform:rotate(1800deg) scale(0);
  }
  to{
    transform:rotate(0) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  <img src="https://image.mel.fm/i/H/HPGUg4dNyo/590.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```